# Adding up all the values for each frequency from FFTW

Tags: fft, fftw

I have run a 3D Fourier Transform using FFTW (`fftw_plan_dft_r2c_3d`) and I would like to sum up the (log of the) values of the transform at every frequency, including the repeated frequencies that aren't actually stored in the output array (I understand the size is `Nx x Ny x (Nz/2 + 1)`).  How do I do this without double counting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. Sorry of my answer is a little long-winded, I want to make sure I don’t make any mistakes. Here goes—

The sum-of-log-magnitudes of a complex-to-complex 3D FFT will be equal to the sum-of-log-magnitudes of a real-to-complex 3D FFT if you double-count all ‘slices’ (of the last dimension) of the latter that are missing from the former.

- If `Nz` is even, that means double-count all slices other than the first and last slices.
- If `Nz` is odd, double-count all slices except the first.

(This is because an even-length real-to-complex DFT includes the -π radians angular frequency (corresponding to a phasor of -1), whereas an odd-length one stops short of it. I never remember this pattern, so I always draw the N=4 vs N=3 phasors around the unit circle to remind myself whether odd or even includes -π rad.)

Here’s an experimental verification of the idea using Numpy/Python, whose notation for real-to-complex FFT I believe matches FFTW’s: generate an `Nx = 10` by `Ny = 20` by `Nz = 8` real array. Compute its complex-to-complex 3D FFT (yielding an Nx by Ny by Nz complex array) *and* its real-to-complex 3D FFT (yielding Nx by Ny by (Nz/2+1) complex array). Verify that the sum-of-log-magnitudes of the former is the *same* as the sum-of-log-magnitudes of the latter if you double-count all but the first & last slices, since `Nz` is even.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.fft as fft

Nx = 10
Ny = 20
Nz = 8

x = np.random.randn(Nx, Ny, Nz)

Xf = fft.fftn(x)
Xfr = fft.rfftn(x)

energyProduct1 = np.log10(np.abs(Xf)).sum()

lastSlice = -1 if Nz % 2 is 0 else None
energyProduct2 = np.log10(np.abs(np.dstack((Xfr, Xfr[:, :, 1:lastSlice])))).sum()

print('Difference: %g' % (energyProduct1 - energyProduct2))
# Difference: -4.54747e-13
```

If you re-run this with odd `Nz`, you will see that the difference between the complex-to-complex and the real-to-complex remains within machine precision of 0.

That `np.dstack((Xfr, Xfr[:, :, 1:lastSlice))` (docs for [`dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html), [`fft.rfftn`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfftn.html)) stacks the `rfftn` output with its 2nd to penultimate slices in the 3rd dimension—penultimate because `Nz` is even, and you don’t want to double-count the 0 or -π DFT bins.

Of course, another way to do this is to compute the sum-of-log-magnitudes over the real-to-complex array, *double* it, then *subtract* the sum-of-log-magnitudes over the first slice and (if `Nz` is even) the last slice.

**tl;dr** Sum the log-magnitudes over the real-to-complex output. Double it. Subtract from this result the sum-log-magnitudes of the very first slice (in the 3rd dimension). If `Nz` is odd, you’re done. If `Nz` is even, also subtract the sum-log-magnitudes of the very last slice.

Comment: Fantastic! I'd discovered this solution late last night but this does a great job explaining why.